# R: Confidence interval and tail probabilities confusion

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

### Introduction

I am working in R and I am getting confused how to compute confidence interval of normal distributions and tail probabilities of unobserved points. I have looked at other posts on here that does not help me answer these questions properly.

### Question Summary:

I have two questions.

1. How to compute the confidence interval of a normal distribution on R knowing the mean, the standard-deviation and the number of samples?
2. How to compute the tail probability of a new point?

---

### Toy Example:

Here is a toy example to illustrate my issue:

Imagine I have some variable `X` that is taken from a normal distribution. I have 50 samples from which I have estimated the mean to be equal to 10 and standard deviation to 2.

```
n = 50
X.mean <- 10
X.SD <- 2
```

By reading the wikipedia page on confidence intervals ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)) I found that I shoud construct it with this equation:

$$\textrm{CI} = \left[\mu + \frac{c_{\alpha}\ast SD}{\sqrt{n}}, \mu - \frac{c_{\alpha}\ast SD}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$$

With $\mu$ = mean, $SD$ = standard deviation and $c_{\alpha}$ = as the $\alpha$ percentile of the distribution.

So if I want to have the 95% confidence interval I would write:

```
# value of the 95% quantile
c_95 <- qt(p = 0.95, df = n-1) 

# CI margin
error <- (c_95 * X.SD / sqrt(n))

# CI values:
ci_interval <- c(X.mean - error, X.mean + error)
```

which gives me `ci_interval` = $[9.5258,  10.4742]$.
(Aleady, I feel that it is smaller than I expected)

Then, I have other issues with the computation of the tail probability with the `pnorm()` function.

On wikipedia, I can read that "*The confidence interval can be expressed in terms of statistical significance, e.g.: "The 95% confidence interval represents values that are not statistically significantly different from the point estimate at the .05 level".*"

So if I compute the tail probabily at the upper confidence interval, I should get 0.025.

But if I do this:

```
pnorm(q = ci_interval[2], mean = X.mean, sd = X.SD, lower.tail = T)
```

I get $0.4062896$ and not the expected 0,0025.

---

What I am understanding / doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want a 95% confidence interval, then you need an area of 0.025 above and below the interval. That means the value in `qt()` should be 0.975, not 0.95. 0.95 leads to a 90% confidence interval.
2. The tail probability will be calculated on the distribution of the sample mean. If $X \sim N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 2)$, and $n = 50$, then $\bar{X} \sim N(\mu = 10, \sigma = 2/\sqrt{50})$. Additionally, if you want to see the value 0.025, you need either the upper tail of the upper limit, or the lower tail of the lower limit. Changing your final call to `pnorm(q = ci_interval[2], mean = X.mean, sd = X.SD/sqrt(n), lower.tail = F)` gives the expected result. (Except for small differences between the t-distribution and normal distribution.)

We don't expected that 95% of new individual X's we observe will fall within the 95% confidence interval. We do expect that if we took many samples of n=50, then 95% of those sample means will fall within the 95% confidence interval. (Technically, we expect that 95% of the 95% confidence intervals will contain the true population mean.)

If you want an interval so that 95% of new X's will be within the interval, what you want is called a "prediction interval".

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and precise answer.